# Получить исключение на конкретном языке

Tags: c#, .net

Текст исключения пробрасывается на основании языка ОС.(Во всяком случае исключения самого .NET)

Можно ли сделать так, что бы пробрасывание ошибки было всегда на 1 языке игнорируя язык исполняемой среды?

Comment: А нужный язык точно установлен на всех ПК?

Answer (score 7):

Язык текста исключения зависит от `CurrentUICulture` потока, в котором произошло исключение. Код

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
        throw new ArgumentException();
    });
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

производит текст

> Der Wert liegt außerhalb des erwarteten Bereichs.

---

Чтобы установить язык для всех потоков одновременно, можно в функции `Main` написать:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = ci;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = ci;
```

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать только для конкретного проекта, и только в коде

```
 #if DEBUG
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 #endif
```

даст вам английские сообщения при дебажной конфигурации